# Prod grade Directory Structure for AWS serverless applications

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, production-environment, aws-serverless

I am trying to figure out what can be the best project directory structure for a serverless application developed using aws also to mention I am using serverless framework. Directory structure I am looking for is a monorepo of multiple micro-services. It should be optimized to accomodate layers, code re-usability, accommodate backend & frontend code, easy to deploy each service individually, should accommodate testing framework so that app is tested in the ci-cd pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one best directory structure. In general what I'd recommend is:

- One `serverless.yml` file per service.
- Your service should encapsulate one domain and one domain only (like Users, Organizations, Events, etc).
- Shared infrastructure (like sns topics, event bridge, authenticators, etc) should be separate (in another `serverless.yml` file or managed by something like terraform, pulumi, etc)

Beyond that, you can read more of my thoughts on [serverless at (team) scale](https://dev.to/aws-builders/serverless-at-team-scale-a8) and on setting up your project so you can [develop against the cloud](https://dev.to/aws-builders/developing-against-the-cloud-55o4)